# Port 80 and 443 is used but i can not modify it

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, port, netstat

If I to the browser on my Laptop and go to `192.168.X.X:80` (ip of raspberry pi), then i receive the error

```
404 page not found
```

If I go to `192.168.X.X:81` which is also unused I receive the chrome error

```
This site can’t be reached
192.168.X.X refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I setup a nginx on the raspberry pi which is working for all other ports (e.g. `70`, `444`, `500`, `8080`) but if I want to assign something to `80` or `443` it is ignored and I receive the `404`.

These errors appear if I have no configuration for port `80` and `81`. Now I add a configuration for port `80` and `81` to my nginx

```
   server{
        listen *:81;
        server_name _;
        root /home/admin/code/minikube;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            index index.html;
        }
    }
    server{
        listen *:80;
        server_name _;
        root /home/admin/code/minikube;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            index index.html;
        }
    }
```

Now port `81` returns the html but `80` still returns the `404`.

the command `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ":80"` (or `443`) has this output

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3825281/nginx: mast
```

this is the same thing as i receive for `81`

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3825281/nginx: mast
```

the nginx config looks like this

if I remove the `80` and restart the nginx server I still get the `404` in the browser but nothing appears with netstat command. This confuses me since a `404` means that something has to be running on this port but netstat shows nothing.

How can I bind something on port `80` with nginx and the change has a affect?

Comment: most likely you have default virtual host file active and that configuration points to some folder which does not have files in it.

Comment: how can I remove/disable them to use port 80 for the nginx?

Comment: search for `listen` directive in a `/etc/nginx/` folder. Most likely you will find active server section